# Import and Export LaTeX presentations in graphical presentation editor

Tags: beamer, miktex, presentations, winedt

I want to find (or create) a graphical presentation editor (or say Winedt macros) that allows text, graphics images and latex formulas to be inserted and formatted interactively.
It should also allow to import/export latex beamer presentations.
I use WinEdt with MikTeX under Windows 7. Few months ago I tried to use Powerpoint 2010 with MathType 6.8, but it works very slow and often freezes.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is **no** such an tool available you are searching for.

Perhaps LyX could help you but I do not know it so it is only a wild guess.